# Is there a way to have a custom class act on a UIView without having the ViewController passed (as reference) upon its initialization?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift4

Example: I have a SpeechSynthesizer class that needs to update something in my UIView when it’s done uttering a piece of text. Since the SpeechSynthesizer class conforms to protocol AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate, it is the one that receives the didFinish signal when the uttering has been completed. The idea here is to keep the ViewController from having too many delegate methods and a long list of protocols to conform to. The workaround I found was to have the ViewController passed in as a SpeechSynthesizer initialization parameter. This way I get to access the ViewController connected to the UIView I want to update from inside the SpeechSynthesizer class. The thing I don’t like about it is that it looks kind of ugly to have the ViewController passed in as a parameter to every single class that needs to use it. So I wonder, which other way I could accomplish this.

I suppose another way to ask the question is: How can I make the function

```
private func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)
```

return something to a ViewController since it's not "called" by it?

Comment: You should use a delegation pattern. That is an appropriate way to decouple your objects.

Comment: Or instead of passing the ViewController in as a SpeechSynthesizer initialization parameter you could pass a closure that does the ViewController manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I added a reply on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-have-a-custom-class-act-on-a-UIView-without-having-the-ViewController-passed-as-reference-upon-its-initialization-Swift4-Xcode9/answer/Andre-Guerra-6). Copying it here:

After doing some research and testing on code of my own here are 2 solutions to this problem.

**Solution 1: The Delegate Pattern:**

Create a custom delegate protocol in the ViewController

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate:class {
    func getViewLayer() -> CALayer
}
```

The ViewController must conform to this newly created protocol and therefore implement all the functions defined by it, so somewhere in the class ViewController you add:

```
public func getViewLayer() -> CALayer {
    return self.view.layer
}
```

Then on my custom class, ReadTextMachine, I added a variable of the ViewControllerDelegate type

```
private weak var viewControllerDelegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
```

The variable must be weak and protocol must be of type class in order to solve a “retain cycle” problem (since both the custom class and the ViewController will point to each other)

You’ll notice now that the function call inside the ViewController is already “callable” from the custom class, so in my ReadTextMachine I added:

```
let viewLayer = self.viewControllerDelegate?.getViewLayer()
self.cameraPreview = CameraPreview(session: self.camera.getSession(), container: viewLayer!)
self.cameraPreview?.addPreview()
```

In the above case, my CameraPreview (yes, a 3rd class in this example) simply adds a camera preview layer on the UIView. For that it needed access to the main View’s layer.

The above code still doesn’t work because our original viewController’s instance hasn’t been passed as reference anywhere in our code. For that we add the following function in ReadTextMachine:

```
public func setViewControllerDelegate(viewController: ViewController) { // call this from the ViewController so that ViewController can be accessed from here.
    self.viewControllerDelegate = viewController
}
```

The above piece of code will have to be called from the ViewController, after we instantiate our custom class (ReadTextMachine), so that the viewControllerDelegate inside it points to the ViewController. So in our ViewController.swift:

```
operatingMode = ReadTextMachine()
operatingMode.setViewControllerDelegate(viewController: self)
```

Another example and explanation can be found in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldz-J7Xrk28) from LetsBuildThatApp. I derived my solution mostly from it.

My current app in development applying the above solution can be found here: [agu3rra/World-Aloud](https://github.com/agu3rra/World-Aloud)

**Solution 2: Notifications and Observers pattern**

This one is a bit easier to understand and follow. The general idea is to have your custom class broadcast a message which triggers a function call on your ViewController since it has an observer setup, waiting to hear that message.

So to give an example, in the context I used it, I have a CameraCapture class which uses AVFoundation to capture a photo. The capture photo trigger cannot immediately return an image, since iOS has a set of steps to execute before actually generating an image. I wanted my ReadTextMachine to resume an activity after CameraCapture had a photo available. (To apply this in the context of the CustomClass triggers ViewController event is basically the same, since both are actual classes in an iOS app as well).

So the 1st thing I did was create a broadcast function since I would use it in many places in my app. I simply placed it in a Utilities.swift file in the Xcode project.

```
public func broadcastNotification(name: String) {
    let notification = Notification.Name(rawValue: name)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notification, object: nil)
}
```

The above function takes a string, which must be a unique notification identifier, and broadcasts it thru NotificationCenter.

In my CameraCapture class, I added a static constant to reference the unique identifier of the message:

```
static let NOTIFY_PHOTO_CAPTURED = "agu3rra.worldAloud.photo.captured"
```

For those who know AVFoundation, a photo is available when event didFinishProcessingPhoto gets executed, so at the end of that I added:

```
broadcastNotification(name: CameraCapture.NOTIFY_PHOTO_CAPTURED)
```

The above is a call to my previously defined utility function.

For my ReadTextMachine class to be able to catch that notification, I added the following on its init() and deinit routines:

```
 override init() {
            super.init()

            // Setup event observers
            let notification1 = Notification.Name(rawValue: CameraCapture.NOTIFY_PHOTO_CAPTURED)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                   selector: #selector(self.processingDoneTakingPhoto),
                                                   name: notification1,
                                                   object: nil)
    }

deinit {
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) // cleanup observer once instance no longer exists
            }
```

Removing the observer is important at deinit so that when your object is deallocated from memory, the observer isn’t left lingering around. The above configured observer triggers a function call inside ReadTextMachine:

```
@IBAction private func processingDoneTakingPhoto() {
    // does my stuff
}
```

That’s it! Again, the entire Xcode project can be downloaded from my project’s Git repository: [agu3rra/World-Aloud](https://github.com/agu3rra/World-Aloud)

Hope this can be of use to others.

Cheers!